# Text File Parsing in Java

Tags: java, file, parsing

I am reading in a text file using `FileInputStream` that puts the file contents into a byte array.  I then convert the byte array into a String using new String(byte).

Once I have the string I'm using `String.split("\n")` to split the file into a String array and then taking that string array and parsing it by doing a `String.split(",")` and hold the contents in an Arraylist.

I have a *200MB+* file and it is running out of memory when I start the JVM up with a 1GB of memory.  I know I must be doing something in correctly somewhere, I'm just not sure if the way I'm parsing is incorrect or the data structure I'm using.

It is also taking me about 12 seconds to parse the file which seems like a lot of time.  Can anyone point out what I may be doing that is causing me to run out of memory and what may be causing my program to run slow?

The contents of the file look as shown below:

```
"12334", "100", "1.233", "TEST", "TEXT", "1234"
"12334", "100", "1.233", "TEST", "TEXT", "1234"
.
.
.
"12334", "100", "1.233", "TEST", "TEXT", "1234"
```

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify: Are you saying you're using -Xmx1024m to start your JVM and you still get an OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: Using a compiled pattern would be better (even roll your own specialist split). But it looks like you just have a lot of object data.

Comment: duffymo,  that is exactly the case.  I am setting the JVM with the -Xmx1024m and getting hte OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Er, you're reading the entire 200MB file into memory?  I'd suggest rather than focusing on trying to make that work, try to figure out how to process the data line by line as you stream it.  Use a BufferedReader() wrapped around a FileReader() and readLine() it line-by-line.  What is eventually happening to this data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing something wrong to me - a whole lotta object creation going on.

How representative is that "test" file?  What are you really doing with that data?  If that's typical of what you really have, I'd say there's lots of repetition in that data.

If it's all going to be in Strings anyway, start with a BufferedReader to read each line.  Pre-allocate that List to a size that's close to what you need so you don't waste resources adding to it each time. Split each of those lines at the comma; be sure to strip off the double quotes.

You might want to ask yourself: "Why do I need this whole file in memory all at once?"  Can you read a little, process a little, and never have the whole thing in memory at once?  Only you know your problem well enough to answer.

Maybe you can fire up jvisualvm if you have JDK 6 and see what's going on with memory.  That would be a great clue.

Comment: The way the questioner is doing it appears to create one large char[] (in a String) and then Strings which are slices of that, which surprisingly is actually the uber memory efficient way of doing it. (Not checked implementation of split. Of course it is all implementation dependent.)

Comment: You are correct on "uber efficient", Tom.  My advice would actually make it worse.  If the problem persists, I think it's processing on the fly and jvisualvm that will help the most.

Comment: Now that we have streams with Java 8, I wonder if this can be done more efficiently using functional programming.  That's what streams were born for.

Comment: If the OP wanted to operate a line at a time, they'd just cut out the list. In terms of performance, if you're not using `parallel()`, the streams API is just adding overhead.

Comment: By all means, parallelStream is the way to go.

Comment: @duffmo It's not going to work very well on a file-based stream.

Comment: Oh well, I guess we'll scrap that.

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure how efficient it is memory-wise, but my first approach would be using a [Scanner](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) as it is incredibly easy to use:

```
File file = new File("/path/to/my/file.txt");
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

while(input.hasNext()) {
    String nextToken = input.next();
    //or to process line by line
    String nextLine = input.nextLine();
}

input.close();
```

Check the API for how to alter the delimiter it uses to split tokens.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at these pages. They contain many open source CSV parsers. [JSaPar](https://github.com/org-tigris-jsapar/jsapar) is one of them.

- [Text file parsing libraries and projects](https://org-tigris-jsapar.github.io/jsapar/links)
- [Java Open Source libraries](http://java-source.net/open-source/general-purpose/jsapar)

Comment: Any particular suggestion ?

Comment: Well, I am a little biased here since I am the author of the JSaPar library. That is why I mentioned it in my answer but one of the other libraries might be better suited for you depending on what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you currently have 3 copies of the entire file in memory: the byte array, the string, and the array of the lines.

Instead of reading the bytes into a byte array and then converting to characters using `new String()` it would be better to use an InputStreamReader, which will convert to characters incrementally, rather than all up-front.

Also, instead of using String.split("\n") to get the individual lines, you should read one line at a time. You can use the `readLine()` method in `BufferedReader`.

Try something like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, "UTF-8"));
try {
  while (true) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null) break;
    String[] fields = line.split(",");
    // process fields here
  }
} finally {
  reader.close();
}
```

Comment: The original way the Strings (should) all share the same backing char[], and therefore be more efficient. A line split probably isn't too bad, because there will just be one char[] per line.

Comment: (And the byte array doesn't need to be in memory at the same time as the array of lines.)

Comment: I was starting to feel like I was having to many copies of the file contents in memory.  I will try this out and see the difference

Answer (score 2):

If you have a 200,000,000 character files and split that every five characters, you have 40,000,000 `String` objects. Assume they are sharing actual character data with the original 400 MB `String` (`char` is 2 bytes). A `String` is say 32 bytes, so that is 1,280,000,000 bytes of `String` objects.

(It's probably worth noting that this is very implementation dependent. `split` could create entirely strings with entirely new backing `char[]` or, OTOH, share some common `String` values. Some Java implementations to not use the slicing of `char[]`. Some may use a UTF-8-like compact form and give very poor random access times.)

Even assuming longer strings, that's a lot of objects. With that much data, you probably want to work with most of it in compact form like the original (only with indexes). Only convert to objects that which you need. The implementation should be database like (although they traditionally don't handle variable length strings efficiently).

Answer (score 0):

While calling/invoking your programme you can use this command : java [-options] className [args...]
in place of [-options] provide more memory e.g -Xmx1024m or more. but this is just a workaround, u have to change ur parsing mechanism.